# LINQ query returning NULL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq query that is trying to compare the column value in a table with the specified input, but it returns NULL always, even though when I use the same query(generated) directly in SQL developer, it generates the desired result..

```
  public IQueryable<Entityname> Getvalue(string input)
    {

        var recordsretrieved = from res in this._Model.Entityname
                                where res.columnA== input
                               select res;

        return recordsretrieved;
    }
```

Am i missing something here?

Query generated in DbMonitor:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1".columnA
FROM TableName "Extent1"
WHERE ("Extent1".columnA = :p__linq__0) AND ROWNUM <= 1
```

The above query shows "no rows affected".. but when i execute in SQL Developer the same query:

```
SELECT 
"Extent1".columnA
FROM TableName "Extent1"
WHERE ("Extent1".columnA = input) AND ROWNUM <= 1
```

It works..

Comment: Are you sure you are pointing your code at the correct database?

Comment: Should `input` be used somewhere?

Comment: @DavidG Yes i used DB monitor.. it shows the correct info.. The query generated by DB monitor shows "no rows affected", but when i execute the same query in my database, it shows the correct result.

Comment: Can you provide also the SQL query that you know works?

Comment: @andrewralon Yes added the input..

Comment: @YacoubMassad Added more info.

Comment: It's impossible for any LINQ query to *ever* return `null`.  It could potentially return an empty set, but it can never return `null`.

Comment: @Servy not even for reference types?

Comment: @MarkC. When I said never, I mean never, as in ever, at least for all LINQ operations that return sequences/queries.  It can return a non-null sequence that has `null` items in it, but what the LINQ query returns can never, itself, be null.

Comment: @Servy I though you meant always when you said never. Thanks for clarifying